# Continuous map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$?

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis

There must be a map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$, since they are the same cardinality.  But is there a construction for a continuous map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$?

I guess what I mean is a map $M : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that as $x$ approaches $x'$, and $y$ approaches $y'$, $M(x, y)$ approaches $M(x', y')$.

If the above doesn't make sense, my apologies, and I hope you are able to figure out what I meant.

Comment: You mean not just a map, but bijection?

Comment: [Continuous bijection from $\mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151202/continuous-bijection-from-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr) at math.SE. It was among to hits when I put into Google: [continuous bijection from r to r2](http://google.com/search?q=continuous+bijection+from+r+to+r2). (In fact, I just start typing and Google autocomplete offered this as one of the queries.)

Comment: @user3313320 The first edit after the question was put on hold pushes the question into [reopen review queue](http://mathoverflow.net/review/reopen/65602). So in general, it is probably better to leave editing to the OP, so that they can try to address the reasons why the question was closed. (Although in this particular case this is no big deal, since this questions is obviously off-topic for MathOverflow. So editing by the OP would not lead to reopening anyway.)

Answer (score 7):

Although it is not stated explicitly, saying about cardinality suggests that you were thinking about bijections. Let me prove that there is no even *injective* continuous map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$. Assume that it exists. Let $B$ be a closed disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then restriction of $f$ to $B$ is a homeomorphism from $B$ to $f(B)$ (any injective continuous map on the compact space is homeo.) $f(B)$ should be a compact connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e., a segment. Take a point $p\in B$ such that $f(p)$ is not an endpoint of the segment $f(B)$. Then $f(B\setminus\{p\})$ is not connected while $B\setminus \{p\}$ is. A contradiction.
Note that, however, there exist continuous surjections from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$ (so called space-filling or Peano curves), but no continuous bijections.

Comment: Essentially the same argument in different terms: there is even no continuous injection $S^1\to \mathbb R$, since in $S^1$ there are two disjoint paths between two points.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider the orthogonal projection. It's continuous (and linear).

Comment: But, reading between the lines, OP wants a bijection.